# Why do I no longer see the usual login screen?

Tags: discussion

I'm "Youvan".  When I try to login, all I see is as option to login with Facebook or Google.  I just installed Facebook.  What's up?  Is there a URL for the normal login page?

Comment: This is weird.  I took out a new username "DeleteMe" for this post, but the post here is "Youvan".  But "Youvan" is back to the status of a brand new user.

Comment: What do you see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login ?

Comment: If you have a DeleteMe did you maybe deleted an earlier profile that got re-connected?

Comment: Are you using the app? Or a browser?

Comment: I did try the link, above.  And I am in Chrome, not an app.  I'll repost here after I try a few more permutations.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of a repost, please edit this post to include more details about your situation so we can give the most accurate answers possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the login page looks like this:

[image]

It has the ability to sign in using your chosen combination of Email and Password.
If your page looks different please make sure you are not using any browser extensions or blockers, and share a screenshot of what you see by [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/362258/edit) your post.